# How can I write a zero-array in a csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I would like to write a csv file in Python 3 with the following format: "index, 0". E.g.:

0, 0

1, 0

2, 0

3, 0

...

I have written the following:

```
csv_file_object = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'w', newline='')) 
Y=np.zeros(2508, dtype=int)
for index, y_aux in enumerate(Y):      
    csv_file_object.writerow([index, y_aux])
```

However, when I have opened the csv file, I can see:

0

1

2

3

...

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Does writing `csv_file_object.writerow([index, str(y_aux)])` solve your problem?

Comment: What tool did you use to open the csv file? I can't reproduce your results.

Comment: Can you help us to understand your actual goal here? Are you trying to create a file with the indicated content? Or are you trying write an `np.ndarray` to a file, adding an index? To put it another way, is `numpy` an essential element of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets the desired output:

```
import csv

with open("my.csv", "w") as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=",")
    for i in xrange(1,10):
        writer.writerow([i,0])
```

But I don't know, what `np.zeros(2508, dtype=int)` is. Perhaps you elaborate a bit on your question.

Comment: [`np.zeroes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) is probably from `import numpy as np`.

Comment: @Robᵩ sounds good, but I haven't worked with numpy ;) so I can not confirm

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to play with file i/o
There's an easier way

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mypath='your path here'

Y=np.zeros(2508, dtype=int)
```

convert to a pandas dataframe

```
U=pd.DataFrame(Y, columns=['zeros'])

U.head()     

    zeros
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
```

save directly to .csv

```
U.to_csv(mypath+'U.csv')
```